# Changing an HTML form input with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to make an editable character sheet for the game Pathfinder. I have a `<select>` for choosing a race and a value set to each race. My value is a string though. What I need to do is when a race is selected I need an input form to be updated.

The Javascript should assign a variable for the stat going to be modified. The user would then type in the base stat number and when finished the javascript would then either add or subtract whatever the modifier is from the value entered by the user.

For example: A dwarf gets a +2 to their constitution score. So when a user selects dwarf from the drop down menu I need my script to recognize that and declare a variable equal to 2. The user would then type in the base stat, let's say 13. Once they are done entering in that number the code would automatically update the input field to 15.

I've figured out how to do this for things like `<p>` but I can't get it for text inputs. I realize the easy thing would be to set the option value to whatever the bonus number is but races effect 3 stats, two positively and one negatively. So I can only understand how to do this with in/else statements. I'm very new to this.

Here is my code. Any help is appreciated greatly.

```
<script>
function createModifier () {

var race = document.getElementById("race");

if (race = "cat") {
    var strMod = 3;
}
else {
    var strMod = 1;
}
document.getElementById("strElm").innerHTML = 10 + strMod;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <div id="raceSelector" class="attribute">
<p><strong>Race</strong></p> 
  <select name="race" id="race">
<option value="aas">Aasimar</option>
<option value="cat">Catfolk</option>
<option value="cha">Changeling</option>
<option value="dha">Dhampir</option>
<option value="dro">Drow</option>
<option value="due">Duergar</option>
<option value="dwa">Dwarf</option>
<option value="elf">Elf</option>
<option value="fet">Fetchling</option>
<option value="gil">Gillman</option>
<option value="gno">Gnome</option>
<option value="gob">Goblin</option>
<option value="gri">Grippli</option>
<option value="hale">Half-Elf</option>
<option value="half">Halfing</option>
<option value="halo">Half-Orc</option>
<option value="hob">Hobgoblin</option>
<option value="hum">Human</option>
<option value="ifr">Ifrit</option>
<option value="kit">Kitsune</option>
<option value="kob">Kobold</option>
<option value="mer">Merfolk</option>
<option value="nag">Nagaji</option>
<option value="orc">Orc</option>
<option value="ore">Oread</option>
<option value="rat">Ratfolk</option>
<option value="sam">Samaran</option>
<option value="str">Strix</option>
<option value="sul">Suli</option>
<option value="svi">Svirfneblin</option>
<option value="syl">Sylph</option>
<option value="ten">Tengu</option>
<option value="tie">Tiefling</option>
<option value="und">Undine</option>
<option value="van">Vanara</option>
<option value="vis">Vishkanya</option>
<option value="way">Wayang</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="attribute">
  <input type="text" onchange="createModifier()"></input>
  <p id="modStr"></p>
</div>
/form>
```

Comment: Java != Javascript

Comment: You want to do `race == "cat"` and not `race = "cat"`

Comment: Well you could use "switch" which seems ideal for this, based on what race the user selects.

Comment: @Anirudh `switch` statements have actually been proven to be slower than just a simple 2-conditional `if/else` statement. By milliseconds though, not a lot

Comment: Where is your `strElm` element?

Comment: @MarkEriksson but here would not be a 2-conditional, since he would have to compare against all possible races which are quite a few! Am I wrong here.

Comment: Make each race an object literal: `var elf = { str: 0, int: 0, wis: -1, Dex: 1, con: -1, cha: 1}` and a default character: `var base = { str: 10, int: 10, wis: 10, dex: 10, con: 10, cha: 10}`

Answer (score 2):

You are saying `if (race = "cat")` which is telling `race` to be equal to `cat`, not determining whether it is or not. You need to use `==` not `=`

Anyway, your problem lies in this line

```
var race = document.getElementById("race");
```

It should be

```
var race = document.getElementById("race").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about change it to

```
if (race.value == "cat") {
var strMod = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake in the above line of code is that you are not comparing strings.

```
if (race = "cat") {
```

should be changed to

```
if (race.value == "cat") {
```